# How to set Precision-ToolTip in Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am crearting one pie chart using Highchart.I stuck on one issue that i cant format value that appearing in tooltip.I want to show only two digits after decimal point.How can  i configre this.Attaching one sample along with this.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `numberFormat`() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat() or solution introduced https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/897

Please take look at example which used numberFormat()

http://jsfiddle.net/2D5nT/44/

Answer (score 2):

For percentage use:

```
this.percentage.toFixed(2)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/dTMWP/

For other:

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,0)
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CAKQH/24238/